# SwiftUI DatePicker in Form Dismisses When Keyboard Appears

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-form, swiftui-datepicker

I have a SwiftUI `Form` with a `Section` that contains a `DatePicker`. The `DatePicker` is set to have a `datePickerStyle` of `CompactDatePickerStyle()`, by default, since it's in a `Form`.

[image: Screenshot of form containing date picker]

When tapping on the `DatePicker`, the overlay is presented:

[image: Screenshot of date picker overlay]

The `DatePicker`'s time is able to be modified by using a gesture, as seen in the following video:

[image: Video of modifying date picker's time via gestures]

In the following video, tapping on the overlaid `DatePicker`'s time to modify it via the keyboard causes the overlay to be dismissed:

[image: Video of attempt to modify date picker's time via keyboard input]

I have also tried adding the following to the `DatePicker` in order to allow for inline date manipulation, hoping for keyboard avoidance:

```
.datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
```

However, the above results in the following:

[image: Video of attempt to edit date inline with keyboard avoidance]

What do I need to change to allow the `DatePicker` to be manipulated via gestures and keyboard input within the form?

Comment: can you supply some code?

Comment: I am experiencing this exact same problem now too! Works perfect outside of the `Form`, but keyboard for `.hourAndMinute` dismisses immediately. I have not found a solution yet, have you?

Comment: I have the same issue here. It must be SwiftUI bug, or? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I too am seeing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise the datepicker so the keyboard wouldn't show over the datepicker, already reported this bug in October 2020 and the ticket is still open. These datepicker don't have keyboard avoidance. Also found an issue with GraphicalDatePickerStyle that can crash the app, ticket still open too.

Comment: is it resolved? can I get a link to the apple bug please @watermamal

Comment: Don't know how to link since it was a report done through Feedback Assistant but I took a screenshot [imgur](https://imgur.com/V1HbPSE) . I'm not sure if its solved or not have not tested it recently but its still open. @tp2376

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard) on the entire Form? I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.