# SwiftUI - Problem with DatePicker inside a Form

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, datepicker

In my app, I have a View like this.

```
struct Test: View {
    @State private var fieldOne = ""
    @State private var fieldTwo = ""
    @State private var fieldThree = ""
    @State private var fieldFour = ""
    @State private var fieldFive = ""
    @State private var dateOne = Date()
    
    @State private var fieldSix = ""
    @State private var fieldSeven = ""
    @State private var fieldEight = ""
    @State private var fieldNine = ""
    @State private var fieldTen = ""
    @State private var dateTwo = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Image("flowers")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 250)
                }
                
                Section {
                    TextField("Field one", text: $fieldOne)
                    TextField("Field two", text: $fieldTwo)
                    TextField("Field three", text: $fieldThree)
                    DatePicker("", selection: $dateOne)
                    TextField("Field four", text: $fieldFour)
                    TextField("Field five", text: $fieldFive)
                }
                
                Section {
                    TextField("Field six", text: $fieldSix)
                    TextField("Field seven", text: $fieldSeven)
                    TextField("Field eight", text: $fieldEight)
                    DatePicker("", selection: $dateTwo)
                    TextField("Field nine", text: $fieldNine)
                    TextField("Field ten", text: $fieldTen)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I tap on `fieldNine` or `fieldTen` and then tap on the second DatePicker, It appear and get dismissed automatically. This happen just on iPhone both on simulator and real devices. What can cause this behavior?

[image: example]

Comment: This answer explains what happens, and suggests a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66142644/1974224

Comment: you have too many states, group them in a struct